# При парсинге на одинаковых тегах часть данных пропадает

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер, curl

Делаю задание по парсингу данных со специального сайта с крайне непонятным движком внутри. Новость выводится в своем теге(он всегда одинаков), я делаю это этим кодом:

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://24gadget.ru/'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);


    //Выделение новостных блоков
    preg_match_all("~<article class=\"news-announce\">(.*?)</article>~is",$result,$post);


        //Перебираем массив и делим по новостям
        foreach ($post[0] as $news){


            //Удаляем ненужное в блоках
            $news = preg_replace("'<div class=\"announce-links clearfix\">.*?</div>'si","",$news);


            //Получаем ссылку на изображение
            preg_match("~<img[^>]*?>~",$news,$img);
            $img = strstr($img[0], '/uploads/');
            $img = strstr($img, '" alt', true);
            $img = "http://24gadget.ru".$img;


            //Удаляем ненужное в блоках
            $news = preg_replace("'<div class=\"announce-text clearfix\">.*?</div>'si","",$news);
            $news = preg_replace("'\(.*?\)'si","",$news);
            $news = strip_tags($news, '<span><a><div><article>');


            //Выделяем ссылку
            $link = strstr($news, 'http');
            $link = strstr($link, '" class', true);


            //Выделяем дату и название
            preg_match("~<a[^>]*?>(.*)</a>~",$news,$article);
            preg_match("~<span[^>]*?>(.*)</span>~",$news,$date);


            //Ищем, сегодняшняя ли новость
            $pos = strpos($date[1], 'Вчера');

                //Если да, то обрабатываем ссылку
                if($pos === false){}
                else {


                    //Получаем дату для сравнений времени
                    $date = intval(str_replace(':', '', strstr($date[1], ' ')));


                    //Запрос самой новости
                    $ch = curl_init();  
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
                    curl_close($ch);


                    //Выделяем текст статьи
                    preg_match_all("~<article class=\"news-announce\">(.*?)</article>~is",$result,$text);




                    //Убираем вееесь шлак в статье оставив только текст
                    $text = $text[0][0];
                    $text = preg_replace("'<div align=\"center\">.*?</div>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<h1[^>]*?>.*?</h1>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<div class=\"announce-meta clearfix\">.*?</div>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<div class=\"big-share\">.*?</div>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<div class=\"announce-tags clearfix\">.*?</div>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<div style=\".*?\">.*?</div>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<!--.*?-->'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace("'<img[^>]*?>'si","",$text);
                    $text = preg_replace('/(<br[^>]*>\s*)+/i','',$text);
                    $text = strstr($text, 'Источник', true);
                    $text = strip_tags($text, '');
                    $text = preg_replace('/\\r\\n?|\\n/', '', $text);


                    //Убираем все пробелы в начале
                    $text = ltrim($text);

                            $arr = array($link, $date, $article[1], $text, $img);
                            $end[] = $arr;
                            $arr = array();





                }
        }



        usort($end, function($a, $b){
            return ($a['1'] - $b['1']);
        });



    //Выводи массив на просмотр 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($end);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Но проблема в том, что даже несмотря на то, что оформление кода одинаковое, часть новостей не парсится, т.е. некоторых новостей достается текст статьи, а некоторые статьи приходят пустыми, хотя в них текст есть. Как такую проблему можно решить?

**P.S.** Если вы читаете после *00:00* и решили проверить код, то замените в **45** строчке `Сегодня` на `Вчера`

Comment: вы не пробовали работать со страницей как DOM документом, а не использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: @teran, я слаб в этой теме, можете пример привести? file_get_contents не парсит сайт

Comment: посмотрите на [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), [PHPQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/),  или стандартный [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) либо другие аналоги, которые не сложно гуглятся.

Comment: @teran, все они используют `file_get_contents`, а с этой функцией данный сайт не парсится. Только cURLом пошло.

Comment: там любому из вышеперечисленного можно скормить строку с данными, а не открывать ссылку, это раз. А во вторых `file_get_contents` имеет туеву кучу настроек, передаваемых через параметр - контекст, что впрочем можно впихать и в эти библиотеки.

Comment: @teran, даже если я им скармливаю готовую строку и получаю данные по нужному тегу, то после регулярок некоторые статьи пропадают и я не могу понять, почему, ведь они сделаны на вид одинаково и они все формируются одинаково.

Answer (score 0):

Полным перебором библиотек и регулярок, поэтапным экспериментам, я нашел проблему. Дело в том, что не в каждой статье есть указание источника, а у меня происходило его стирание, а т.к. его нет, то стирался весь текст:

```
$text = strstr($text, 'Источник', true);
```

И если добавить проверку на его наличие, то все работает:

```
$pos = strpos($text, 'Источник:');

 if($pos === true){
   $text = strstr($text, 'Источник', true);
 }
```

Оставлю это, может кому-то пригодится.

**P.S.** Зато был придумал за это время более удобный и короткий способ парсинга, иногда полезно иметь ошибки.

Answer (score -1):

Можно просто:

```
if($pos) $text = strstr($text, 'Источник', true);
```

Это равносильно `if($pos == true)`, не проверяет тип, но работает быстрее и меньше текста.